# Calling a component in ColdFusion 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a form submit problem. I'm using ColdFusion 10 and I can't see what is wrong with my codes. 
The form is submitted to an action page. In the action page I call a component:

```
 <cfif IsDefined("Form.Run")><!--- Form is submitted, call this comp --->

   <CFSET UpdObj = New cfcomponents.GComp.g_IsExist_1(Form.Sh, Form.LY)>
   <cfdump var="#UpdObj#><cfabort>

 </cfif
```

I got the following error message:
Invalid CFML construct found on line 117 at column 127.
I learned that this is the right way to call a component in CF10. Why do I get this error message???
There is nothing in line 117

Comment: Is that the exact code? You are missing a closing quote here `<cfdump var="#UpdObj#>`, should be `<cfdump var="#UpdObj#">`. And a closing bracket here `</cfif`, should be `</cfif>`. You will need to post the actual error with the referenced code from those line numbers. The line number in the error message is not always correct.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer... I realize his syntax is correct for CF 10 and he specified that version.

Comment: What file has the error? The 'action page' or the component itself? It is entirely possible that you are calling the CFC correctly, but that there is a syntax error in the component itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax errors. As others have mentioned, you may use `createObject`, but using the `new` operand may better fit your style since it's what is in your code example:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "run")><!--- Form is submitted, call this comp --->

   <cfset UpdObj = new cfcomponents.GComp() /> <!--- Calls init() if it exists --->
   <cfset exists = UpdObj.g_IsExist_1(Form.Sh, Form.LY) />
   <cfdump var="#UpdObj#" abort="true" />

 </cfif>
```

Comment: That was my typo. In my actual codes I have the closing quotes and closing bracket.

Comment: So what is your exact error message? What is line 117 in reference to your code sample above?

Comment: You cannot use the `new` operand when directly calling a method on a CFC in your example. You must call the constructor prior to calling the method all in one: `<cfset UpdObj = new cfcomponents.GComp().g_IsExist_1(Form.Sh, Form.LY) />` or you use `createObject`, then you can do: `<cfset UpdObj = createObject("cfcomponents.GComp").g_IsExist_1(Form.Sh, Form.LY) />`